# Spark creating empty hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hue, hive-metastore

I'm currently working on a project with on premise servers. My goal is to write a dataframe into a Hive metastore. However, I've encountered an issue wherein Spark successfully creates the table, but it doesn't populate it with data. While I can observe the table structure and its columns in the metastore, it remains devoid of data.

Does anyone have any insights or ideas to help me resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

I attempted to write the dataframe using spark.write, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Can you share your code ?